# Can air miles be applied retroactively when registering a OneWorld (BA) account?

Tags: loyalty-programs, british-airways, oneworld

Can air miles be applied retroactively when registering a OneWorld (BA) account?

What is the time limit if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [BA](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/executive-club/avios):

> If you find you’re missing some Avios or Tier Points on your account
>   you can claim them back within six months of your flight. **New members
>   can even claim Avios and Tier Points for any British Airways flights
>   flown in the three months before joining**.

Note that you [can't claim](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/claimfaq/execclub/_gf/en_us#ecearnclaimmissingfaq_en_main-8)* for flights on partners, you'd have to check to see if you could claim on the partner airline themselves.

> No credit will be granted for flights you flew on our airline partners
>   prior to your enrolment in the Executive Club.

- Post-login link